# file_put_contents not working on remote image

Tags: php

I have the following code to mail myself an image

```
$img = file_get_contents("http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/threats/hazards_d3_7_contours.png");
file_put_contents("hazards_d3_7_contours.png",$img);

$message = $img;

$headers = "From: me";
$headers = "Content-type: image/gif";
$subject = '3-7 Weather Hazard Forecast';
$to = 'me@gmail.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

however the image I am getting is broken
any idea why?

Comment: step one, is it valid image on your server?

Comment: You're sending the email as an `image/gif` when the image is a PNG.

Comment: There is no such link exist. Then how you are getting the broken image 
`http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/threats/hazards_d3_7_contours.png`

Comment: @Deonia http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/threats/hazards_d3_7_contours.png works for me

Comment: @user2421414 I dont know it wont open here . May be chinese internet problem . :(

Answer (score 0):

The image has the file extension `.png`, yet you are sending it as `image/gif`. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the email with the mimetype `image/gif` even though the image retrieved from the remote server is an `image/png`. You then overwrite the header with the `from` value. You're looking for something like this:

```
$headers   = [];
$headers[] = 'From: me';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: image/png';

$subject = '3-7 Weather Hazard Forecast';
$to      = 'me@gmail.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, implode(PHP_EOL, $headers));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a brace? If it's a square brace update your PHP **right now!**

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
public function store()
{

    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents("img/" . $_FILES['myfile']['name'], $file);

    return $_FILES['myfile'];

}
```